# How to map new array with dynamic keys from existing array values without looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wonder how to create a new array with keys from the existing array object's property values. I know how to do it with a loop but is there is a better solution such as using the array.map function?

**Input Array:**

```
[ {id: 1, name: 'John', surname: 'Smith'}, {id: 2, name: 'Peter', 'Black'} ]
```

**Requested result:**

```
[ { 'John' : { id: 1, surname: 'Smith'}}, {'Peter': {id: 2, surname: 'Black'}} } ]
```

I still receive Error *Unexpected token '.'* with the key name.

```
var arr1 = [ {id: 1, name: 'John', surname: 'Smith'}, {id: 2, name: 'Peter', surname: 'Black'} ];
let arr2 = arr1.map( e => ( { e.name : {id: e.id, surname: e.surname } } ) );
```

Comment: let arr2 = arr.map(e => ({ [e.name] : {id: e.id, surname: e.surname}}));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap the dynamic key name in a square bracket `[]` like:

```
[e.name] : {id: e.id, surname: e.surname }
```

```js
var arr1 = [ {id: 1, name: 'John', surname: 'Smith'}, {id: 2, name: 'Peter', surname: 'Black'} ];
let arr2 = arr1.map( e => ({ [e.name] : {id: e.id, surname: e.surname} }));
console.log(arr2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an expression as a **key**, then wrap it in square brackets:

```js
let arr2 = arr1.map(e => ({[e.name]: {id: e.id, surname: e.surname}}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way; You were too close, just you forget to bind the key using `[obj.name]`

```js
  
let data = [{ id: 1, name: 'John', surname: 'Smith' }, { id: 2, name: 'Peter',surname: 'Black'}]
let finalResult =data.map(obj => ({ [obj.name]: { id: obj.id, surname: obj.surname } }))
console.log(finalResult)
```

Comment: Thank you all guys for your help. It was stupid question for sure... :-)